# How to crop the video via the surfaceview/surfaceholder class?

Tags: android, surfaceview, surfaceholder

Here is my question: how to crop the video via the surfaceview/surfaceholder class?

In my survey, the only way to crop the video is to use the TextureView::setTransform/setLayoutParams,  am I right?

But there is only one interface working with surfaceholder class in my 3rd-party video player library: VideoPlayer::setDisplay( SurfaceHolder holder ). If I don't use the TextureView class, is it possible to resolve this problem?

I look forward to every possible suggestions,  thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think there's a trivial API to do what you want.  One possibility is to use OpenGL ES to transform the video.  See e.g. "texture from camera" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and follow example of [VideoView](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-0/android/widget/VideoView.java) to place video screen output the way you need.

Not sure if there are any other easier options available.

Comment: Dear vladimir, in my knowledge, videoview will scale the video output. What I need is to crop the video, to show the region of interest.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned one of the options can be extending SurfaceView to display video the way you want.